# Monodevelop Updating Packages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, monodevelop

Im using MonoDevelop Version 5.10

When I create a new Project (MVC-Razor-Project), everything works OK.
However, I notice that I have 3 packages that need updates.

As soon as I update the packages, the page no longer loads (cleaned and rebuilt without an compliation warnings).

The error I get is: `System.InvalidOperationException
    Could not locate Razor Host Factory type:      System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was go into the web.config and change Version=5.2.0.0 to 5.3.2.0